# Play Framework examine HTTP request

Tags: playframework, webserver, jersey, jax-rs, playframework-2.1

I was wondering how to examine an HTTP request in Play Framework 2.1. The only information I can find on the documentation is via the `conf/routes` mechanism:

```
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

but this will only allow us to get the parameter `id` from the path. How do I access other part of the request, such as header or query params? In other words, what are Play's equivalents of JAX-RS `@HeaderParam`, `@FormParam`, `@QueryParam` and such?

Comment: are you using Java or Scala for your controllers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within an action, you can get the request header using the `request()` method, for instance, in Java:

```
public static Result index() {
  // example of a Header
  String userAgent = request().getHeader("User-Agent");

  // example of a query parameter
  String q = request().getQueryString("q");
  ...
}
```

You can take a look at the API for [Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html) or [Scala](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.RequestHeader).

Comment: Thank you nico_ekito! I'd be also very happy if you could you point me to some more extensive guide: the one on the [website](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaHome) seems to only scratch the surface.

Comment: I do not know any particular guide, instead of the official doc. There are also some books out there http://bit.ly/playscala and http://bit.ly/playjava

Comment: Can you please at least provide where request() came from? For novices' sake please.

Comment: It is inherited from the [Controller](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/java/play/mvc/Controller.html) class

Answer (score 5):

Better use a constant than a hardcoded String, in Scala the code is

```
import play.mvc.Http

val userAgent: String = request.headers.get(Http.HeaderNames.USER_AGENT).get
```

Answer (score 4):

This line worked for me:

```
implicit request => val User-Agent:String = request.headers.get("User-Agent").get
```